# Adding a View All button to a website section and styling it

Tags: html, css

I am learning to create a website by downloading and editing contents.

I have created a section in the home page which shows the images of all stores of a shop. I need to display 3 stores image on the home page and add a **View all** button in the right bottom side of the section.

I have tried many ways but can't get it done in a good way.

Below is the HTML Code :

```
<!-- OUR STORES Section -->
<section id="stores" class="bg-light-gray">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Our Stores</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#storeModal1" class="store-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="store-hover">
                        <div class="store-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/store/store01.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="store-caption">
                    <h4>Store 01</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Location 01</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 store-item">
                <a href="#storeModal2" class="store-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="store-hover">
                        <div class="store-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/store/store02.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="store-caption">
                    <h4>Store 02</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Location 02</p>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Could you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) showing what you have and what you want?

Comment: check this, it might be what you want https://jsfiddle.net/n7oo7dLk/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just adding a new row, text aligned to right with the button ?

edit: See other response, this one only tell how to add the HTML button, not the javascript of it.

```html
<!-- OUR STORES Section -->
<section id="stores" class="bg-light-gray">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Our Stores</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#storeModal1" class="store-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="store-hover">
                        <div class="store-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/store/store01.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="store-caption">
                    <h4>Store 01</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Location 01</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 store-item">
                <a href="#storeModal2" class="store-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="store-hover">
                        <div class="store-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/store/store02.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="store-caption">
                    <h4>Store 02</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Location 02</p>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>

        <!-- HERE -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View All</button>
          </div>
       </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This worked !
As I am a beginner, can you just tell me where class="btn btn-primary"and "col-md-12 text-right"  is defined.

Comment: For the alignment : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load them asynchronously (resp. you have them in HTML file already) you can wrap them into div, which is set as a hidden in css `display:none`

Then you need Javascript and create event which handles DOM interaction on click.

I made a little sample for you with CSS and jQuery (Javascript Framework):
https://jsfiddle.net/ta53jfwo/

I hope it helps!

Comment: I don't have any idea about JavaScript.